# The explicit solution of Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One form of the Riccati equation is the following ODE:

$$
y''(t)+K(t)y(t)=0.
$$
Can we find an explicit solution of $y(t)$ such that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$? By "explicit" I mean the solution can be expressed as some integral form involving $K(t)$.

Comment: You may have a hard time. Even the simple case $K(t)=t$ has a rather non-elementary solution involving Airy functions. This kind of DEs are usually solved through integral transforms or Frobenius' method.

Comment: No! You cannot write the explicit solution to this equation anyhow. This would be great if you could. You then at once solved half or even more problems in physics in 1d. The only thing you can explicitly express is the asymptotic behavior of the solutions at regular points of $K(t)$. Those asymptotics are very accurate and may be used safely for many purposes. Search for the WKB approximation.